# Why is Lambda throwing a DescribeInstances error when I have that action included on my role policy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a fairly simple Lambda that I'm going to use to start and stop EC2 instances on a cron schedule. In it, I'm checking to see if the instance is already running or not.

```py
# get instance
instance = ec2.Instance(instance_id)
  
# return if instance already running
if instance.state['Name'] in ["pending", "running"]:
  return True
```

When I execute the Lambda, I get the following error:

`An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.`

Here is a snippet of my policy, copied directly from IAM and edited to remove account info:

```json
{
  "Sid": "",
  Effect": "Allow",
  Action": [
    "ec2:StopInstances",
    "ec2:StartInstances",
    "ec2:DescribeInstances"
  ],
  "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:############:instance/i-#############"
},
```

For what reason would I be seeing this error under these circumstances? I've confirmed that my code that starts the instance works, I only see an error when I attempt to get the status of the instance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767975/why-does-applying-a-condition-to-ec2describeinstances-in-an-iam-policy-fail

Comment: @MarkB I saw that answer and interpreted it in the completely opposite direction. Separating the "DescribeInstances" action to a separate statement with "*" resources worked.

Comment: @S.Davenport Completely unrelated to your question. But something that relates to what you are trying to achieve. Refer [this AWS reference](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/instance-scheduler-on-aws/) for a cloudformation which lets you do starting and stopping of instances based on a schedule